# HTML entities not displayed correctly when data is populated using knockout binding

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

HTML entities(®,©,€.. etc) not getting displayed correctly when using knockout bindings.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
      <body>
            <!-- This is a *view* - HTML markup that defines the appearance of your UI -->

            <!--Data appearing via binding-->
            <p>Product name: <strong data-bind="text: productName"></strong></p>

            <!--Static data-->
            <p>Product name:<strong>ABC&reg;EFG</strong></p>

            <script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/knockout-3.4.0.js"></script>
            <script src="js/script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

      </body>
</html>
```

Javascript(script.js):

```
function AppViewModel() {
    this.productName = ko.observable("ABC&reg;EFG");
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the binding from `text` to `html` fixed the issue.

```
 <p>Product name: <strong data-bind="html: productName"></strong></p>
```